# Private Pages Navigation in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

we´re starting our very first liferay 7 project and I am having troubles creating private user pages. We have 7 Pages that we want the user to have and those pages need to be private because we want to use the private messaging portlet.

I created a site template and I assigned it to my new user´s dashboard. 
So the pages get created and the user has access to them (I verified by entering the URLs manually).

But how can the user navigate ? I haven´t found any way to show the available pages to the user. The Menu only allows the user to click on "My Dashboard" and that´s it ...

Any help is welcome.

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: How did you finally solved this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give friendly url first to your site
You can give in site by changing the friendly url.
You can also provide different urls for private as well as public pages.
For public pages liferay appends **web** /your-friendly-url 
and for private pages it appends **group** /your-friendly-url
Then give the url under Control Panel-->Configuration-->Instance Settings
and set the Default Landing Page property to /group/your-friendly-url.

They have mentioned it clearly as stated below:
Enter the friendly URL that is used by both public and private pages. The friendly URL is appended to **http://ip/web** for **public pages** and **http://ip/group** for **private pages**.

Comment: I still am not sure how this solution helps - I still do not see how can a menu with private pages can be enabled and visible to a logged in user. Other way put - I can set landing page to be one private page, but how can I still display the private page links in a menu while the user will be thrown in a public page after login ?